# Azure Service Principal create new certificate with PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

How can i create a new certificate for my service principal in azure with powershell?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Have you referred to the online [documentation](https://support.jetglobal.com/hc/en-us/articles/235636308-How-To-Create-a-SHA-256-Self-Signed-Certificate) already? This gives a step by step process using powershell.

This is creating a self signed certificate but for production, you should get one which is signed by a Certificate Authority(CA) [LINK](https://www.digicert.com/blog/what-is-a-certificate-authority).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this doesnt help me. I want to create it directly in Azure with a powershell command.